# How to add 2 key values from array object and update in 1st key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I am having an array of two objects:

```
let abc = [
  {amount: 1000, rate: 4},
  {amount: 100,  rate: 2},
  {amount: 700,  rate: 1}
];
```

I want to multiply `amount * rate` and update in `amount` key.

Expected output:

```
let output = [
  {amount: 4000, rate: 4},
  {amount: 200,  rate: 2},
  {amount: 700,  rate: 1}
];
```

Comment: The *input* and *output* are not syntactically valid!!

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
let data = [{amount: 1000, rate: 4}, {amount: 100, rate: 2},{amount: 700, rate: 1}];

let result = data.map(o => ({...o, amount: o.amount * o.rate}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.prototype.map()`:

```js
   let abc = [{amount: 1000, rate: 4}, {amount: 100, rate: 2}, {}, {amount: 700, rate: 1}]
   abc.map(x => {
       if(!x.amount || !x.rate){  // account for empty objects
           return x;
       }
       return {...x, amount: x.amount * x.rate}
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let abc = [{amount: 1000, rate: 4}, {amount: 100, rate: 2},{amount: 700, rate: 1}]
var output = abc.map(field => {
field.amount = field.amount * field.rate
return field
})
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use forEach, If you don't want to create a new Array.

```js
let abc = [
  {amount: 1000, rate: 4},
  {amount: 100,  rate: 2},
  {amount: 700,  rate: 1}
];

abc.forEach(item => item.amount = item.amount * item.rate)

console.log(abc)
```